# $\int_0^1 f(x)dx \times \int_0^1{\frac{1}{f(x)}}dx \geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Assume that $f$ is a measurable function on the interval $[0,1]$ such that $0<f(x)<\infty $ for $ x \in [0,1]$ Prove that

$$\int_0^1 f(x)dx \times \int_0^1{\frac1{f(x)}}dx \geq 1$$

I am trying to see on how can I apply holder's inequality to solve this porblem , but I have haven't had a breakthrough so far. Please let me know if I am thinking on the right track or if I should try to think of some other way of proving this inequality

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Cauchy Schwarz with $\sqrt{f(x)}/\sqrt{f(x)}$.

Comment: Use $\int f(x)g(x)\ dx \leq \left( \int f(x)^2\ dx\right)^{1/2}\left( \int g(x)^2\ dx\right)^{1/2}$

Comment: All too easy.  (+1)